# Android - What happen to my Project?

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I am new to android development. Yesterday night I was working on my project. It was working well. But today morning I open my project I got R error. Then only I noticed my project everything is disabled.

[image]

I don't know what is happening. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Please clean your project

Comment: clean your project and build again  ...

Comment: Hi @Giru. I have already tried to clean. But I am getting error. `Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'VijayClient'.
Path must include project and resource name: /VijayClient`..

Comment: @Vijay Have you deleted the source in the workspace?

Comment: have you check source in the workspace? If the project is there try to open in different workspace.try after restarting eclipse.

Comment: Hi@Sripathi.. I did not delete anything.

Comment: Finally I changed the workspace. I is working. But still now I don't know why all my folders are closed in my previous Workspace..

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean and build your project, and if that didnt work you need to check your manifest and style folder for any error that sometimes it wont hint you for errors in there.

Comment: Hi @Rod_Algonquin.. Please check my uploaded image. There all the folder is disabled(Closed).

Answer (score 0):

It happened to be before, I had some issues with Java x64 and Android SDK, I couldn't fix it and someone told me to switch java, eclipse and sdk to 32 bits.

This was around 6 months ago, dont know if its the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to the change in the path of the library required by the Project.
Go in the Java Build Path option and try to remove and add again the library.

Answer (score 0):

Tick the android sdk package name in project properties.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I changed the workspace. It is working. But still now I don't know why all my folders are closed in my previous Workspace.. Thanks to all..